# Game breaking Unity bug, too many players breaks the game even if destroyed

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am an indie developer working on my own on a project in Unity called Kingdom of Lies, examples of my work can be found at LokisKingdom at Minds.com. (warning: NSFW content) I've had a bug in this game for a long time, right from the earliest stage of development. Weapons are picked up by destroying the player and spawning a new one. This is fine for the most part, but if multiple weapons are picked up at the same time, it spawns multiple players. This is actually fun at first, because controlling a little group is entertaining, but if that group starts picking up multiple weapons, in a matter of seconds it can spawn 145 players, and the game grinds to a halt. You can't move, you can't quit, can't even alt F4, you have to kill the process to stop it.

As the game is getting closer to a finished state, I went back over the problem again. I managed to solve the problem of the extra players being spawned. I simply created a list and destroyed any players past the first. But this is the weirdest part, the game breaks anyway. Even if there are no other players running around, if you pick up enough extra weapons at the same time, the game will chug slower and slower, and eventually freeze, and you kill the process. At this point I'm stumped. Apparently it's not about the number of objects on screen, something about the interaction itself is what's breaking the program.

Here are some examples of the code in question.

in GUIJar.cs (called in Update() )

```
void HandleMultiplePlayers()
{
    GameObject[] PileOfPlayers;
    PileOfPlayers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("User");

    numPlayers = 0;

    if (PileOfPlayers.Length > 0)
    {
        foreach (GameObject thePlayer in PileOfPlayers)
        {
            numPlayers++;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("PLAYERPILE", numPlayers);

            if (numPlayers > 1)
            {
                Object.Destroy(thePlayer);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

later in GUIJar.cs

```
void OnGUI() {

    if (domain == 1)
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Score " + score + " Snowflakes " + enemiesRemaining + " Heads " + heads, customstyle);
    }
    else
    {
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 10, 100, 20), "Score " + score + " Remaining " + enemiesRemaining + " Heads " + heads, customstyle);
        GUI.Label(new Rect(10, 70, 100, 20), "Number of Players: " + numPlayers, customstyle);
    }
    }
```

in GunBehavior.cs

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other) 
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PLAYERPILE", 0) < 4)
    {
        if (gunType == 0)
        {
            if (SpawningOnce == false)
            {

                if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player")
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
                    {
                        SpawnNewWeapon("Player(gun)", "BatObject", other.gameObject);
                    }

                    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
                    {
                        SpawnNewWeapon("Player(gun)", "BatObject", other.gameObject);
                    }
                }

                if (other.gameObject.tag == "Player(knife)")
                {
                    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Tab))
                    {
                        SpawnNewWeapon("Player(gun)", "KnifeObject", other.gameObject);
                    }

                    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(1))
                    {
                        SpawnNewWeapon("Player(gun)", "KnifeObject", other.gameObject);
                    }
                    // Process continues for each type of player and item picked up
                }
           }
      }
 }
```

}

Also in GunBehavior.cs

```
void SpawnNewWeapon( string pickUpName, string dropName, GameObject theObject)
{
    if (PlayerPrefs.GetInt("PLAYERPILE", 0) < 4)
    {
        SpawningOnce = true;
        Instantiate(Resources.Load("Switch", typeof(GameObject)));
        GUIJar.blood = false;

        GameObject weaponclone;
        weaponclone = Instantiate(Resources.Load(dropName, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        weaponclone.transform.position = theObject.gameObject.transform.position;

        GameObject clone;
        clone = Instantiate(Resources.Load(pickUpName, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        clone.transform.position = theObject.gameObject.transform.position;

        Object.Destroy(theObject.transform.parent.gameObject);
        Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

If you go to my minds and download the game, it contains a folder with all of my scripts, in case you want to look through Movement.cs, Movement2.cs, and Movement3.cs, or PlayerBehavior.cs . But other than the complexity of that code, I think it is unrelated to this problem. Fairly sure the root of the problem is in the code I just posted. Perhaps I should just remake the player class to be the one switching between weapons rather than the weapon destroying and replacing the player, but the processes used are pretty deeply embedded in the code and would be hard to change. If possible I would prefer to fix the existing code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

[Sorry if this is a bad question, it's my first time asking one.]

Comment: have you tried using the profiler to see where the memory is being used?

Comment: No I haven't..... to be honest I don't know what you mean, could you elaborate? If not I'll just look it up myself.

Comment: so many weird issues with this code.  Interestingly I've recently been watching people coding games in unity on Twitch and quite a few of them end up code that's just a mess.   One guy was stuck on some of his code, I went away, came back and he was still stuck,  I kindda felt sorry for him so I rewrote it in 15 minutes and he progressed easily after that.   So don't be afraid of restructuring, it is often the key to making progress.  However, I'm no unity expert, but to me `Object.Destroy(theObject.transform.parent.gameObject);` looks suspicious. Is that really the object you want to destroy?

Comment: I can't see the rest of the code, but I got a feeling that's not the right thing, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you, I am currently in the process of remaking the code, I am running into difficulties but something has to be done about it. I wrote this stuff when I was still pretty new to coding. I think I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: As for the destroy transform.parent.... I think that's correct, if only because it was working before, it's been a while since I made this, but I think it's just grabbing a tag from a child object and then destroying the object in charge of it.

Comment: I don't think the profiler would help, if the game is locking up. Some data might be captured, but there's no way the OP could view it before the editor froze. I would try using a debugger and pausing Unity to find out what the it's actually doing. Then unpause and repeat several times. Failing that, try writing the name of each function call to a log file.

Comment: Thank you, I will do that. The problem seems to be caused by two things, first the game doesn't like it when I pick up more than one weapon, also now that I'm remaking the code, I'm running into a problem where it just loops around infinitely picking up weapons until it crashes in the same manner described above, even though I'm using GetKeyDown, and even tried GetKeyUp, for some reason it just keeps triggering anyway. Very frustrating and confusing...

Comment: @Loki Can you look at the stack trace of the pickup function? It will probably tell you where it's being triggered, and I don't think the answer will be `GetKeyDown`, unless you accidentally made something recursive. Or if your newly instantiated object also handles the same key event.

Comment: Well this is embarrassing. I don't know about the stack trace, I'd probably have to look it up.

Comment: @Loki The first thing I'd check is the last thing I mentioned--your newly instantiated object may be responding to the same key event as the older object, and it will progress infinitely. By the way, if you don't mention a user by name, only the user that wrote that question/answer will notice the comment.

Comment: @piojo Thank you, that's precisely what caused the problem, looks like if I didn't figure it out myself you had me covered anyway. The game is now fit for sale, at least bug wise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169929/discussion-between-piojo-and-loki).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem. What I did was I commented out the code inside of the weapon classes themselves, then moved the weapon switching code into the player class, then I went into the GUIJar class and made a little function that waits a quarter of a second before the bool triggers back to false. Then inside the player class, when the weapon switch occurs, the player calls the GUIJar wait function, triggers the bool to true, and is unable to pick up weapons until the bool is false again.

This solved both the multiple player spawning problem and the infinitely respawning weapons. That was the only major bug in my game, believe it or not. Now after a bit of polish, and lots of bug testing to make sure this works correctly, I will now feel much safer when I think about submitting this game for sale.

[Edit, sure, of course, sorry for the lateness of this edit:]

In PlayerBehavior.cs:

```
void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
{
    GameObject gui = GameObject.FindWithTag("GUIJar");

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(1) || Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.Tab))
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GunPickup")
        {
            if (gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
            {
                gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().SetWeaponSwitch();

                // Object.Destroy(other.gameObject);
                DropWeapons();
                SpawnReplacementPlayer("Player(gun)", other.gameObject);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "ShotgunPickup")
        {
            if (gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
            {
                gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().SetWeaponSwitch();
                //Object.Destroy(other.gameObject);
                DropWeapons();
                SpawnReplacementPlayer("Player(shotgun)", other.gameObject);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "GrenadeLauncherPickup")
        {
            if (gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
            {
                gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().SetWeaponSwitch();
                //Object.Destroy(other.gameObject);
                DropWeapons();
                SpawnReplacementPlayer("Player(grenade)", other.gameObject);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "BatPickup")
        {
            if (gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
            {
                gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().SetWeaponSwitch();
                //Object.Destroy(other.gameObject);
                DropWeapons();
                SpawnReplacementPlayer("Player", other.gameObject);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "KnifePickup")
        {
            if (gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
            {
                gui.GetComponent<GUIJar>().SetWeaponSwitch();
                //Object.Destroy(other.gameObject);
                DropWeapons();
                SpawnReplacementPlayer("Player(knife)", other.gameObject);
            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Also in PlayerBehavior.cs:

```
void SpawnReplacementPlayer(string pickUpName, GameObject theObject)
{
        Instantiate(Resources.Load("Switch", typeof(GameObject)));
        GUIJar.blood = false;

        GameObject clone;
        clone = Instantiate(Resources.Load(pickUpName, typeof(GameObject))) as GameObject;
        clone.transform.position = this.gameObject.transform.position;

        Object.Destroy(theObject);
        Object.Destroy(this.gameObject);
}
```

In GUIJar Class:

```
IEnumerator WaitToSwitchWeapons(float waitTime)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitTime);

    WaitForWeaponSwitch = false;

}

public void SetWeaponSwitch()
{
    if (WaitForWeaponSwitch == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(WaitToSwitchWeapons(0.25F));
        WaitForWeaponSwitch = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code you please display the code you changed for future reference?